# Google map is taking too long to load

Tags: google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5

I am opening a google map on page load and add pointers to it on the basis of data fetched from the database. But the problem here is it takes approx 3-4 minutes to load, cpu utilization reaches to 100% and RAM is also consumed a lot. Below is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div id="map" style='height: 85vh;'></div>
        </div>
      
     </div>
</div>

<script>

  
  var infowindows = [];
  var notification_location, cirle_area_for_notification = null;
  function initMap() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      // center: {lat: markers[0].lat, lng: markers[0].lng},
      center: {lat: -33.826668, lng: 151.231526},
       type:['(regions)'],
       componentRestrictions: {
        country: ['aus']
      }
    });
    var icon, content = '';
    <% @users.find_in_batches(batch_size: 200) do |users| %>

      <% users.each do |user| %>

          <% if user.staff? %>

            icon = "<%= image_url 'blue.svg' %>";
            content = ''
                + 'Name: <b><a href = "<%= admin_staff_path(user.staff_profile.id)+"?path="+request.original_url %>" target = "_blank"></a></b></br>'
                + 'Role: <b>staff</b></br>'
                + 'Phone Number: <b><%= user.phone_number %></b></br>'
                + 'Qualification: <b><%= user.qualification_levels&.last&.name %></b></br>'
                + 'Radius: <b><%= user.address.radius %></b></br>'
                + 'Centers in same zone: <b><%= user.staff_active_centers_in_same_zones.pluck(:user_id) %></b></br>';


          <% else %>

            icon = "<%= image_url 'orange.svg' %>";
            content = ''
                + 'Name: <b><a href = "<%= admin_show_center_path(user.center_profile)+"?path="+request.original_url %>" target = "_blank"><%= user.user_name %></a></b></br>'
                + 'Role: <b>center</b></br>'
                + 'Phone Number: <b><%= user.phone_number %></b></br>'
                + 'Staffs in same zone: <b><%= user.center_active_staffs_in_same_zones.size %></b></br>';
          <% end %>

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: content
      });
      infowindows.push(infowindow);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
          {
              position: {lat: <%= user.address.latitude %>, lng: <%= user.address.longitude %>},
              map: map,
              title: '<%= user.user_name %>',
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon),
              id: '<%= user.id %>',
              users_in_same_zone: '<%= user.center_active_staffs_in_same_zones.pluck(:staff_user_id) %>'
          }
      );

      //Click event on marker
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
          close_map_info_windows();
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

        <% end %>

    <% end %>


  // Close map infowindow
  function close_map_info_windows(){
    for (var i = 0; i < infowindows.length; i++) {
      infowindows[i].close();
    }
  }


</script>
<script defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= Rails.application.secrets.google_api_key %>&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Below is the controller code

```
@users = User.active.accepted.joins(:address)
              .includes(:address, :qualification_levels, :staff_profile, :center_profile, :center_active_staffs_in_same_zones, :staff_active_centers_in_same_zones)
```

If I increase the batchsize more than `200`, the response time increases. I am looping in view because I need to assign the values to the javascript functions

I am using `RAILS5`.

Any suggestions to optimize this page?

Answer (score 1):

As first thing, it looks like you're having [a N+1 issue](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).
Try adding `.includes` for models like `staff_profile`, `qualification_levels`, `address` or `staff_active_centers_in_same_zones` for your users query.
Something that could help you to identify those models is the [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) gem.

In any case, your code smells like something could be wrong as you potentially could load more than 200 user points in the map (telling because of the `batch_size: 200` in your query), but only you know what should be doing your page.

And unrelated, but also move the query logic to the controller. In the view looks the wrong place to call it using a MVC approach.

Comment: I am already using includes in the controller, no N+1 is not there , if I increase the batchsize more than 200, the response time increases. I am looping in view because I need to assign the values to the javascript functions, question updated with the controller code

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma I'm not questioning the use of `find_in_batches`, just saying that loading +200 records in a page, looks like a design problem (BTW, how many records are you loading there?). Probably you should need another approach, maybe using caching, refactor the way how you're saving that data, decreasing the amount of data to display. If you're using PostgreSQL,maybe Postgis could help with geodata.Anyway,with the info you're providing isn't enough to know what could be source of your problem,try at least to identify what's the source of the slowness and add that info to the question.